# How to find path for outlook so I can send emails with scripts

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have created a powershell script to send csv files automatically using Task Scheduler. I feel as if I am making a silly mistake with my pathing as nothing is sending.

I have testing the script below.

```
if($args.Count -lt 1)
{
Write-Host "Use: SendMail.ps1 <"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office\Microsoft Outlook 2010.lnk">"
Write-Host
Write-Host  "<"C:\CSV">"
Write-Host
exit
}

$FullPath=$args[0]

#Get an Outlook application object

$o = New-Object -com Outlook.Application

$mail = $o.CreateItem(0)

#2 = High importance message
$mail.importance = 2

$mail.subject = "CSV File"
$mail.body = "Here is the CSV file."

#separate multiple recipients with a ";"
$mail.To = <---->
#$mail.CC = <OTHER RECIPIENT 1>;<OTHER RECIPIENT 2>

# Iterate over all files and only add the ones that have an .csv extension
$files = Get-ChildItem $FullPath

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {

$outfileName = $files[$i].FullName
$outfileNameExtension = $files[$i].Extension

# if the extension is the one we want, add to attachments
if($outfileNameExtension -eq ".csv")
{
$mail.Attachments.Add($outfileName);
}
}

$mail.Send()

# give time to send the email
Start-Sleep 20

# quit Outlook
$o.Quit()

#end the script
exit
```

I believe that the following is incorrect:

```
Write-Host "Use: SendMail.ps1 <"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office\Microsoft Outlook 2010.lnk">"
```

But I am unsure as to what the path should be.

Comment: You don't need Outlook path since you are using COM to drive Outlook.

Comment: Wouldn't it be far easier to use the [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6) cmdlet whet sending emails using Task Scheduler ? That way you don't have to rely on the existance of Outlook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path should be something like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Outlook.exe
```

This link has a few methods of finding the path to the executable of a running process:

http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=152